# How to move controls from one window to another one in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-controls

I have an application that contains a plugin system. The plugins define their menu and toolbar entries of the main application.

I thought on creating on the plugins a UserControl just to hold plugins menu and toolbar entries (and be able to define them using xaml) to put them on the main application. When I try to attach them to the main Window I get an exception saying

> Element already has a logical parent. It must be detached from the old
>   parent before it is attached to a new one

I've tried to remove first the element in this way:

```
    public System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem Menu
    {
        get 
        {
            ((StackPanel)(_controlItems.Content)).Children.Remove(_controlItems.ItemMenu);
            return _controlItems.ItemMenu;
        }
    }
```

But I get the same exception. Any thoughts?

Comment: Not quite sure I follow what you are trying to do, but a general comment is that it's generally bad design to put a function like that in a getter. Getters shouldn't have side effects.

Comment: I have a plugin assembly. The plugin has to be loaded on the main application and the main app will have a menu entry to execute the plugin. The plugin defines the menu entry that the main app will show. To define the entry with xaml the plugin creates a user control with a public menu entry. The main app thru the getter takes the public menu entry and puts it in its own menu. Is it clearer now? I can put an example if needed.